# kubernetes tail logs of newly created containers where the name is unknown yet

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I would like to know how to tail the logs of all containers including containers that are created after I started the follow (`k logs -f po-xyz`).
Tools like `kubetail -f` also don't have this feature, or did I use it wrong ?

Comment: If you are able to use other tools than kubectl, have a look at [stern](https://github.com/stern/stern). You can specify pod names as regular expressions, so you can query pod names like `deployment-name*`

Comment: Are you looking for a cluster-level logging setup, or something else?  Is there any scope on the "all containers"?

Comment: With the help of `kubectl get pods --watch` you can get the recently created pods, with the name of pod you can get `kubectl logs --all-containers=true`.

Comment: thanks @SaiChandraGadde is there a tool that already connects the pod watch command with the logs ?

Comment: thanks @usuario, I give that a try. Let's see.

Comment: watch command is used to know the name of the pod which is created recently, for logs we should use kubectl logs podname --all-containers=true(forgot to add pod name in the previous command)

Comment: @SaiChandraGadde please read the question carefully.